# "Query Optimization" : Neo4j Query builds a cartesian product between disconnected patterns -

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I’m supposed to have graph of multiple nodes(more than 2) with their relationships at 1st degree, second degree, third degree.

**For that right now I am using this query**

```
WITH ["1258311979208519680","3294971891","1176078684270333952",”117607868427845”] as ids 
MATCH (n1:Target),(n2:Target) WHERE n1.id in ids and n2.id in ids and n1.id<>n2.id and n1.uid=103 and n2.uid=103 
MATCH p = ((n1)-[*..3]-(n2)) RETURN p limit 30
```

In which 4 nodes Id’s are mention in **WITH[ ]** and next **[*..3]** it is used to draw **3rd degree graph** between the selected nodes.

**WHAT the ABOVE QUERY DOING**

After running the above query it will return the mutual nodes in case of second degree [*..2] if any of the 2 selected nodes have mutual relation it’ll return.

**WHAT I WANT**

*1)     First of all I want to optimize the query, as it is taking so much time and this query causing the Cartesian product which slow down the query process.

*2)     As in this above query if any 2 nodes have mutual relationship it will return the data, I WANT, the query will return **mutual nodes** attached with all selected nodes. Means if we have some nodes in return, these nodes must have relation to all selected target nodes.*

Any suggestions to modify the query, to optimize the query.

Comment: Assuming that a `uid` is supposed to be a "unique ID", why are there multiple `Target` nodes with the same `uid`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for to avoid the cartesian product issue with the given query

```
WITH ["1258311979208519680","3294971891","1176078684270333952",”117607868427845”] as ids 
    MATCH (n1:Target),(n2:Target) WHERE n1.id in ids and n2.id in ids and n1.id<>n2.id and n1.uid=103 and n2.uid=103 
    MATCH p = ((n1)-[*..3]-(n2)) RETURN p limit 30
```

I suggest to use this one below

```
MATCH (node1:Target) WHERE node1.id IN ["1258311979208519680","3294971891","1176078684270333952"]
MATCH (node2:Target) WHERE node2.id IN ["1258311979208519680","3294971891","1176078684270333952"]
and node1.id <> node2.id
MATCH p=(node1)-[*..2]-(node2) 
RETURN p
```

It will remove the cartesian product issue.
Try this..